# Failed to create a directory: logs/fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

With TensorFlow 1.13.1, I can save the logs with Tensorboard but when I upgrade to TensorFlow 2.0.0_alpha0 the same code gives me the error:

```
"Failed to create a directory: logs/fit/20190411-193710\train; No such file or directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]"
```

What can I do to  correct this for TensorFlow 2.0.0_alpha0

```
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def create_model():
return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

log_dir="logs/fit/"
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, 
histogram_freq=1)

model.fit(x=x_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=5, 
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test), 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Comment: Does the `"logs/fit/"`directory exist? You could make it if not.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0.0 create  "logs/fit/" directory but directory is empty. And a new error message: 'Cannot stop profiling. No profiler is running.' If I use Tensorflow 1.13.1 I can save logs but can't start "tensorboard --logdir=logs/". I save logs with Tensorflow 1.13.1 and open them with Tensorflow 2.0 :) I give up.

Comment: try this:
`"logs\fit"`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in windows environment.
For Windows try this

```
log_dir="logs\\fit\\"
```

Or the best solution would be to make this machine independent.
Try this

```
import os
log_dir= os.path.join('logs','fit','')
```

You will get the same result but this will work on any Operating System